# I have few basic questions on R Stem and Leaf Plot

Tags: r

This data when I plot - `60` `85` `72` `59` `37` `75` `93` `7` `98` `63` `41` `90` `5` `17` `97`

```
stem(data)

 0 | 577
 2 | 7
 4 | 19
 6 | 0325
 8 | 50378
```

Now If I reconstruct data it is `5`, `7`, `7`, `27`, `60`, `63`, `62`, `65`, `85`, `80`, `83`, `87`, `88`

This does not produce the input in reverse.

Answer (score 2):

With the default scale, you see that numbers left of the bar go up by two - hence anything after the 4 is forty-something or fifty-something:

```
> stem(d,scale=1)

  The decimal point is 1 digit(s) to the right of the |

  0 | 577
  2 | 7
  4 | 19
  6 | 0325
  8 | 50378
```

Using `scale=2`, you'll see numbers left of the bar go up by one, so now you can get exact reconstruction of your input, since you input integers:

```
> stem(d,scale=2)

  The decimal point is 1 digit(s) to the right of the |

  0 | 57
  1 | 7
  2 | 
  3 | 7
  4 | 1
  5 | 9
  6 | 03
  7 | 25
  8 | 5
  9 | 0378
```

Going further you can even split it by first and second five within each decade:

```
> stem(d,scale=4)

  The decimal point is 1 digit(s) to the right of the |

  0 | 57
  1 | 
  1 | 7
  2 | 
  2 | 
  3 | 
  3 | 7
  4 | 1
  4 | 
  5 | 
  5 | 9
  6 | 03
  6 | 
  7 | 2
  7 | 5
  8 | 
  8 | 5
  9 | 03
  9 | 78
```

Stem plots *do not* always guarantee you can reproduce the data by reversing the process, and that's not what they're for.

Answer (score -1):

try this
S=c(60, 85, 72, 59, 37, 75, 93, 7, 98, 63, 41, 90 ,5 ,17 ,97)
;stem(S,scale = 2)
A value of scale = 2 will cause the plot to be roughly twice as long as the default.